# How to detect text shadow

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect text with shadow effect in image. Background, text color, text size is not fixed.

[image: Text sample]

I have tried this method:

1. Add threshold to get shape from text similar to rectangle. 
   [image: Text after threshold.]
2. Find rectangle contour.

But it does not work how I want, because my images come in different backgrounds, fonts and text sizes.

What method would be the best for text with shadow detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All text in this area has a one color. You can calculate count of pixels with each color and sort this list. Color of the text will be on the bottom of this list. When color of the text is known, you can set the threshold more accurately.

```
def get_count(pixels_in_this_area):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for pixel_color in pixels_in_this_area:
        count[pixel_color] += 1

count_with_text = get_count(area_with_text)
count_without_text = get_count(area_without_text)
for color in count_without_text.keys():
    if color in count_with_text:
        count_with_text[color] -= count_without_text[color]

count_list = list(count_with_text.items())
count_list.sort(key=lambda: x[1])  # sort by count of pixel with this color
text_color = count_list[-1][0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for respond. Are you sure last count entry should return text color? Because for me returning only random background color.

Comment: Try to use only different of background and text areas.

Comment: I forget say: these areas must have equal size. Else you need to normalizing "count" to size.

I was happy to help)